# How can I validate two fields like password and confirm password in Struts 2?

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, struts2, annotations

I am doing web application in that I want to validate two fields in the JSP form. In registration filed I have so many fields. In that I want to validate password and confirm password  fields.

**Below is my code:**

**`Action` Class:**

```
@Length(min = 6, max = 20)
@Column(name = "PERSON_PASSWORD", nullable = false, length = 20)
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

@Length(min = 6, max = 20)
@Column(name = "PERSON_CONFORMPASSWORD", nullable = false, length = 20)
public String getConformPassword() {
    return conformPassword;
}
```

Now, how can I validate the two fields contain the same data?

Comment: You can use Struts2-JSR303 plugin which provides this type of validation out of the box for you.https://github.com/umeshawasthi/jsr303-validator-plugin

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi I did validation by using Hibernate. If I use struts2 there we can directly put condition in RequiredFielsdValidator annotation. like that here is it possible?

Comment: I believe you are using Hibernate Validator? and you can use that with this plugin.this is how you can do that https://github.com/umeshawasthi/struts2-jsr303-example/blob/master/src/main/java/org/demo/validation/actions/dto/CrossFieldConstraintsDTO.java

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi I downloaded but I can't able to add this plugin to my Netbeans IDE, Could u please give me the exact URL thank u very much

Comment: how you installing it ? are you using maven or something similar or you can just download jar from following location http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/github/umeshawasthi/struts2-jsr303-validation-plugin/1.0/

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi I am not using MAVEN.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44143/discussion-between-codegeek-and-umesh-awasthi)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a non-field custom validator to validate any number of fields. For this purpose you should create a custom validator that extend `ValidatorSupport` and implement `validate` method which is inherited from `Validator` interface but doesn't have default implementation. You should write this implementation to do custom validation. For example you want to create a `RetypeValidator` which validates two fields have the same value. It could look like

```
public class RetypeValidator extends ValidatorSupport {

  private String value = null;

  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }
  public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  private String retypeValue = null;

  public String getRetypeValue() {
    return retypeValue;
  }

  public void setRetypeValue(String value) {
    retypeValue = value;
  }

  @Override
  public void validate(Object object) throws ValidationException {
    String value = (String) parse(this.value, String.class);
    String retypeValue = (String) parse(this.retypeValue, String.class);
    if (value != null && retypeValue != null && !value.equals(retypeValue))
      addActionError(getDefaultMessage());
  }
}
```

then you have to add this validator to the configuration in the `validators.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator Config 1.0//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-config-1.0.dtd">

<validators>
  <validator name="retypeValidator" class="org.custom.struts.vaidators.RetypeValidator"/>
</validators>
```

Now, you have a custom validator name that you could use with `@CustomValidator` annotation.

```
@Validations(
    customValidators = @CustomValidator(type="retypeValidator", message="the value and retype value should be the same",
      parameters = { @ValidationParameter( name = "value", value = "${password}" ), @ValidationParameter( name = "retypeValue", value = "${conformPassword}" )})
)
```

Note, `password` and `conformPassword` are OGNL expressions used to parse when being validated.

Comment: great way to have a custom validator for two (or more) fields (+1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use if statement to compare

```
if(password == conformPassword)
{
    //TO-DO
}
else
{
    //TO-DO
}
```

Comment: I want to compare two fields in within annotation .thanking you for your quick response

Comment: This code doesn't answer a question and should be either comment or deleted altogether.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(getPassword().equals(getConformPassword()){
{
//code
}
```

Comment: thank u Manish I want to compare two fields in within annotation .thanking you for your quick response

Comment: This code doesn't answer a question and should be either comment or deleted altogether.