# Reusing Custom Expression Validator in Struts 2

Tags: java, validation, struts2, struts-validation, struts2-convention-plugin

In Struts 2 we can develop `@CustomValidator` which can be used in application wide

```
@CustomValidator(type = "CustomerNumberValidator", fieldName = "customerNo")
```

For validation *more* than one field we use `@ExpressionValidator`

```
@ExpressionValidator(expression = 
"( (!''.equals(account.firstName) && (!''.equals(account.lastName) )
   || (presonalAccount == false)", 
   key = "validate.account.name")
```

If the expression is too complicated and needs to work on *more* than one field we use OGNL to call the static method. The static method will do the validation and return a `boolean` for example

```
@ExpressionValidator(expression = "@foo.bar.CalendarUtil@compareDates(fromDate,toDate)", key = "validate.date.before")
```

Above is some how a *Custom* Expression Validator !

And we use `@foo.bar.CalendarUtil@compareDates` in application wide to make this validation for us.

Is there another approach which enables us to use a custom wide validator?!

Is there any custom expression validator which can be added to Struts and we can call it in `Action` in the way we use `@CustomValidator`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a Custom Validator (not field related):

```
public final class CompareDatesValidator extends ValidatorSupport {
    private String fromDate; // getter and setter
    private String toDate;   // getter and setter    

    @Override
    public void validate(Object o) throws ValidationException {
        Date d1 = (Date)parse(fromDate, Date.class);
        Date d2 = (Date)parse(toDate, Date.class);

        if (d1==null || d2==null || d2.before(d1)){
            addActionError(getDefaultMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Register the custom validator in `validators.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC
     "-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator Config 1.0//EN"
     "http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-config-1.0.dtd">
<validators>
    <validator name="compareDatesValidator" 
              class="org.foo.bar.CompareDatesValidator"/>
</validators>
```

Use the validator in an action:

```
private Date startDate; // getter and setter
private Date endDate;   // getter and setter

@Validations(
    customValidators={
        @CustomValidator(type="compareDatesValidator", 
            message="Dates provided are not valid."
            parameters={
                @ValidationParameter(name="fromDate", value="${startDate}"), 
                @ValidationParameter(name="toDate",   value="${endDate}")})})
public String execute(){
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for can you please update your answer and let me know, in an i18n app, how can I read custom message key in `compareDatesValidator` and set it in `addActionError`

Comment: It seems another question to me, so it would be better to post it as another question (like "how to get i18n messages from within a custom validator")...

Comment: Well, I have asked it at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054378/struts-2-how-to-get-i18n-messages-from-within-a-custom-validator

Answer (score 1):

You can use non-field custom validator if you need to validate several fields. Non-field custom validator should extend `ValidatorSupport` and implement `validate` method. Then apply a custom validator in your `-validation.xml` or use `@CustomValidator` annotation. There you can add custom expressions as `@ValidationParameter` and parse them when you doing validation.

**Note:**

This technique I used *firstly* in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20845823/573032) answer:

> ```
> public class RetypeValidator extends ValidatorSupport {
>
>   private String value = null;
>
>   public String getValue() {
>     return value;
>   }
>   public void setValue(String value) {
>     this.value = value;
>   }
>
>   private String retypeValue = null;
>
>   public String getRetypeValue() {
>     return retypeValue;
>   }
>
>   public void setRetypeValue(String value) {
>     retypeValue = value;
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public void validate(Object object) throws ValidationException {
>     String value = (String) parse(this.value, String.class);
>     String retypeValue = (String) parse(this.retypeValue, String.class);
>     if (value != null && retypeValue != null && !value.equals(retypeValue))
>       addActionError(getDefaultMessage());
>   }
> }
> ```

Another option is to override `validate` method of the `ActionSupport` class. The call to this method is controlled via [`validation` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/validation-interceptor.html). This method of validation is known as *programmatic* and is used by default regardless of validators applied during *declarative* validation.