# Struts 2 how to get i18n messages from within a custom validator

Tags: struts2, internationalization, validation

How is it possible to get the message from key in the custom validator ?! As mentioned in [Struts 2 - reusing Custom Expression Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28038827/struts-2-reusing-custom-expression-validator) you can get default message as :

```java
public void validate(Object o) throws ValidationException {

    //Do some logic
    addActionError(getDefaultMessage());
}
```

Comment: Use `getMessage`, btw downvote isn't mine.

Comment: I was asked by @Andrea Ligios  to ask it in different question :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28038827/struts-2-reusing-custom-expression-validator/  I was mislead ;)
Thanks for answer please send the answer so I can accept it!

Comment: Upvoted both... Now it fits SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom validator should extend `ValidatorSupport` class, which has a convenient method `getMessage(Object object)` to get i18n messages set with `key` parameter.

So inside `validate` method instead of calling `getDefaultMessage` (which simple returns default message) call `getMessage` which will evaluate `key` parameter with additional `messageParams`.

```java
public void validate(Object o) throws ValidationException {
    //Do some logic
    addActionError(getMessage(o));
}
```