# How to short-circuit a @CustomValidator?

Tags: java, validation, struts2, struts-validation, struts2-convention-plugin

Consider below sample, which checks if `fromDate` and `toDate` are valid  dates and if `fromDate` is less than `toDate`:

```java
@CustomValidator(type = "DateValidator", 
            fieldName = "fromDate",
         shortCircuit = true),

@CustomValidator(type = "DateValidator", 
            fieldName = "toDate",
         shortCircuit = true),

@CustomValidator(type = "CompareDatesValidator", 
              message = "validate.date.jalali.same.or.before",
         shortCircuit = true, 
           parameters = {
        @ValidationParameter(name = "fromDateParam", value = "${fromDate}"),
        @ValidationParameter(name = "toDateParam", value = "${toDate}") 
               })
```

The `DateValidator` extends the `FieldValidatorSupport` and the `CompareDatesValidator` extends the `ValidatorSupport`

Although I have `shortCircuit` the `DateValidator`s, but the  `CompareDatesValidator` always run, which is not correct. Can I fix this ?!

Comment: Is this answers your question? From the docs: `Plain validator takes precedence over field-validator. They get validated first in the order they are defined and then the field-validator in the order they are defined. Failure of a particular validator marked as short-circuit will prevent the evaluation of subsequent validators and an error (action error or field error depending on the type of validator) will be added to the ValidationContext of the object being validated.`.

Comment: @AleksandrM thanks I have seen it, but unfortunately it does not helped. The validation should be short circuit but it is not !

Comment: `Plain validator takes precedence over field-validator.` - Meaning your `CompareDatesValidator` will be executed first. Meaning short circuit will happen only after that. Convert it to field validator and it should work like you want.

Comment: @AleksandrM *less commenting, more answering* FTW ! :)

Comment: I thought that because i wanted to use more than one field during validaiton, I should use extend `ValidatorSupport`. Well I changed `CompareDatesValidator` to extend `FieldValidatorSupport` but I get `Null pointer` from strust do you need stacktarce ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained [in the documentation](https://struts.apache.org/docs/validation.html#Validation-Short-CircuitingValidator).

> **Plain validator takes precedence over field-validator.** They get validated first in the order they are defined and then the field-validator in the order they are defined. Failure of a particular validator marked as short-circuit will prevent the evaluation of subsequent validators and an error (action error or field error depending on the type of validator) will be added to the ValidationContext of the object being validated.

Then your actual execution order is:

1. **CompareDatesValidator** (plain)
2. **DateValidator** (field `fromDate`)
3. **DateValidator** (field `toDate`)

The problem is that it will be executed first, but since its check is a composite check based on two fields, the atomic check on the fields itself should be performed first.

But this is how the framework works, so **you need to *workaround* it**.

If [your plain validator is still this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28043351/1654265) (even if with [some modification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28055013/1654265)), you could avoid the check and ignore the error in case the input is not valid, letting this validation happen where it belongs, in the Field Validators:

```
public final class CompareDatesValidator extends ValidatorSupport {
    private String fromDate; // getter and setter
    private String toDate;   // getter and setter    

    @Override
    public void validate(Object o) throws ValidationException {
        Date d1 = (Date)parse(fromDate, Date.class);
        Date d2 = (Date)parse(toDate, Date.class);

        if (d1==null || d2==null){
            LOG.debug("Silently disabling Plain Validator. Check performed by Field ones");
        } else if (d2.before(d1)){
            addActionError(getDefaultMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

You only need to remember to always put the **Field Validators** in the same validation stack of the **CompareDatesValidator**, or the *"Date not valid"* errors will be silently swallowed.

Comment: The `DateValidator` are complicated functions, so I end up repeating the  `DateValidator` in the `CompareDatesValidator`. Like: `if( !valid(d1) || !valid(d2)) {   LOG.debug("Silently disabling Plain Validator. Check performed by Field ones");}` Thanks for the answer